# Stuck at the passing data from database to view

Tags: laravel

I am still beginner at laravel, and i have problem about undefined variable when i want to pass data from the controller

here is my route

```
 Route::get('/jelajahi-search', 'TourismController@srch');
Route::get('/jelajahi','TourismController@index');
```

here is my search function in the controller

```
    public function srch(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, ['cari'=>'required']);

            $search = $request->get('cari');

            $posts = Tourism::where('namatempat', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->orWhere('kabupaten', 'like', "%$search%")
                ->paginate(1)
            dd($posts);
            return view('vendor.jelajahi')->with('tourismSearch',$posts);
       }
```

and here is my view

```
@foreach ($tourismSearch as $tour)
            <tr>
                <th>
                <td>
                    <img src="{{ URL::asset('/jelajahi-image/'.$tour->path_gambar) }}" style="width: 25%; height: 25%;"><br>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Nama tempat : {{$tour->namatempat}}<br>
                    Kabupaten   : {{$tour->kabupaten}}<br>
                    Kecamatan   : {{$tour->kecamatan}}<br><br>
                </td>
                </th>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

thank you

Comment: Do you mean, that `$toursmSearch` is undefined in your view? Try it with `$tourism_search`.

Comment: @barfoos yes it's undefined in my view, already tried it, won't work

Comment: Try `view('vendor.jelajahi')->withPosts($posts)` in your controller. You should be able to reference it with `$posts` in your view. Please be sure that `/jelajahi-search` and `/jelajahi` do not share a view, since the `$posts` are just defined for `vendor.jelajahi`.

Comment: yep already tried it too, still won't work, got undefined error

Answer (score 0):

It seems your search doesn't return any results.

Try to use this check:

```
@if ($tourismSearch)
    @foreach ($tourismSearch as $tour)
        <tr>
            <th>
            <td>
                <img src="{{ URL::asset('/jelajahi-image/'.$tour->path_gambar) }}" style="width: 25%; height: 25%;"><br>
            </td>
            <td>
                Nama tempat : {{$tour->namatempat}}<br>
                Kabupaten   : {{$tour->kabupaten}}<br>
                Kecamatan   : {{$tour->kecamatan}}<br><br>
            </td>
            </th>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Also, you can check for `$posts` contents by using `dd($posts);` before `return view` clause.

Comment: no, it's still not working with that :(but thanks for answering tho

Comment: Do you get error? The thing is if your `$tourismSearch` is empty (which it looks like) then you shouldn't see a list of tours.

Comment: yes i got the error, Undefined variable: tourismSearch . when i try Session::get('tourismSearch') as $tour) , it works but everytime i refresh the page, the session is deleted

Comment: Well, there is no `Session` in your original code. Why are you using `Session`?

Comment: no, i just want to try every way possible. sorry i am just a beginner in laravel

Comment: Just try to use my code and `dd();`. It should work. I think the problem in an empty search result and not in passing variable into a view.

Comment: It will be helpful if every time you'd tell what exactly error do you get. It's impossible to help you if you just saying it's not working.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to write it, here is the error ErrorException in e22fa730b48fef20310002c127cdd698e536a06e.php line 85:
Undefined variable: tourismSearch (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\skripsiproject\resources\views\vendor\jelajahi.blade.php)

Comment: And what `dd($posts);` before `return` clause shows you?

Comment: it shows that error, let me update the code first so u can see